# Change position of an element in a numpy arrray

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing

I am trying to move a element in a numpy array to first position as follows.

```
a = [[1, *2, 3]
     [4, 5, 6*]
     [7*, 8, 9]]
```

it should be like:

```
a = [[2, 1, 3]
     [6, 4, 5]
     [7, 8, 9]]
```

Is there any numpy function that can help to do that?

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.roll` will help you do this if you roll just the first slice of the array.
The second list in the zip is the index of the item you wish to move to the front.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m = range(1,10)
>>> m = np.reshape(m,(3,3))
>>> m
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> for (row, column) in zip(range(3),[1,2,0]):
...     m[row][:column+1] = np.roll(m[row][:column+1], 1)
... 
>>> m
array([[2, 1, 3],
       [6, 4, 5],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: this does not actually match the expected output

Comment: I think roll will keep the order same, but in my output the order is different. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Good spotting Padraic!! :) Now modified so that just the first part of the array is rolled to get the right result.